# Inject Anchor Tag into <td> after table is constructed

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

I am using an external react module called react-json-to-table (https://github.com/thehyve/react-json-to-table) to dynamically render a table from a JSON input. The problem is that all values in this table are string values and it can't be anything else due to the module implementation.

This is the codesandbox link that the module gave as an example. I wanted the URL portion to be an anchor tag but I am running into issues. https://codesandbox.io/s/jn3z0mmw2v

I saw that if I edit the rendered HTML table directly and inject an anchor tag it behaves as I want it to but this should be done programmatically.

[image]

[image]

I think it can be done through the DOM but not quite sure how to do that through react code as opposed to pure Javascript. Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: looks like its not supporting, you have to fix library source code

Comment: yeah trying see if I can add it externally without touching original library, but it's looking like it's not possible...

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found a solution using react-dom/server.

I used the renderToString function to get the component's HTML code and manipulating it directly.

If you do renderToString(any kind of component) and store that output, it will be the string representation of the generated HTML code.

I just manipulated the string and injected the anchor tag directly and rendered that string by using